# How to add a space between a title equal to half of the page width?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

So I'm writing a CV and want to have my address and email on the same line but separated. I.e:

Address: [Space] Email:[Where the centre of the right column would begin]

[image]

Attached is my attempt.

```
   \documentclass[a4paper]{report}
   \usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    {\huge{\textbf{Name}}}      
\end{center}

\textbf{Address} %Space goes here \textbf{Email}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've changed the tagging from "align" to "horizontal-alignmrnt".  "align" specifically applies to questions about the multi-line math display environment of `amsmath`, which isn't relevant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this. Below there's a fixed-width (`.5\linewidth`) box used to set the **Address:**, or using a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \huge\bfseries Name
\end{center}

\noindent
\makebox[.5\linewidth][l]{\bfseries Address:}%
\textbf{Email:}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{.5\linewidth} @{} l }
  \bfseries Address: & \bfseries Email:
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```